# Webflow in php language

Tags: php, spring-webflow

I recently developed a web application in Java EE with Spring framework. I also used the **Spring webflow** project to define my flow (*a strict navigation that user must follow to access certain pages*, eq: the [shopping cart](http://wheelersoftware.com/articles/spring-web-flow-2.0.html) in ecommerce website).

I'm now on **PHP** web project. And I want to know if there is any **equivalent** to SpringWebflow in php (framework or not). 
Otherwise what's the *best practices* (eq: to design an shopping cart application) in php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'm late, but googling I found a webflow implementation on a php framework calle YUPP

http://code.google.com/p/yupp/source/browse/trunk/YuppPHPFramework/core/mvc/webflow